# Problems converting html from a website to pdf using yahp.jar

Tags: java, html, url, pdf

This code keeps giving me an error saying that the urlForBase must be a valid URI.
The lines containing this error are in bold and cursive. Anyone know what the issue is? I'm positive the url is an actual correct url.

```
        CYaHPConverter converter = new CYaHPConverter();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/steveweyns/Desktop/summary.pdf");
        Map properties = new HashMap();
        List headerFooterList = new ArrayList();

        properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.PDF_RENDERER_CLASS,
                IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FLYINGSAUCER_PDF_RENDERER);
        try {
            //properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FOP_TTF_FONT_PATH, fontPath);
            ***converter.convertToPdf("http://biz.yahoo.com/e/" + correctSummaryPass + "/" + ticker + "10-k.html",***
                    IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A4P,
                    headerFooterList,
                    "",
                    out,
                    properties);
        } catch (IHtmlToPdfTransformer.CConvertException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AnnualReportSummary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AnnualReportSummary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AnnualReportSummary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AnnualReportSummary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Show us end result of that url part..

Comment: org.allcolor.yahp.converter.IHtmlToPdfTransformer$CConvertException: urlForBase must be a valid URI.
 at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter.convertToPdf(CYaHPConverter.java:225)
 at annualreportscraperfinal.AnnualReportSummary.download(AnnualReportSummary.java:193)
 at annualreportscraperfinal.AnnualReportSummary.main(AnnualReportSummary.java:46)

Answer (score 0):

```
*converter.convertToPdf("http://biz.yahoo.com/e/" + correctSummaryPass + "/" + ticker + "10-k.html",***
                    IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A4P,
                    headerFooterList,
                    "",
                    out,
                    properties);
```

change to :

```
*converter.convertToPdf("http://biz.yahoo.com/e/" + correctSummaryPass + "/" + ticker + "10-k.html",***
                    IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A4P,
                    headerFooterList,
                    null,
                    out,
                    properties);
```